# Bitbucket Pipeline npm install fails with "npm ERR! fatal: unable to access"

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to run test cases in my node app using `Bitbucket pipeline` as follows.

```
image: channagayan/node_test:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - cd NodeApi && pwd && npm install
          - npm test
```

But it fails giving following error

```
+ cd NodeApi && pwd && npm install
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/NodeApi
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://git@github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://git@github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-01T09_15_55_789Z-debug.log
```

My Dockerfile is as follows,

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  python-software-properties \
  pkg-config \
  wget \


     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#node installation goes here....

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

#opencv installation goes here....

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3001
```

It seems like Bitbucket is not accessing the internet from the docker container. Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: Seems like CA Certs are not installed in the image try adding a RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates